# How to use constructor function to add method java?

Tags: java

I would like to add method through my constructor and use it after :

```
RegularAxis lon = new RegularAxis(){
    public String returnHello(){
         return "hello";
    }
};

lon.returnHello();
```

I cannot access my new method. is there an other way?

Comment: That's not how Java works, why do you want to do this instead of defining the method in the normal way?

Comment: The method has to be added in the class declaration, or via a setter which takes a function argument or something similar, like a lambda

Comment: Because my regularAxis is part of a library, I cannot edit it. And i would like a custom method

Comment: In your example, you are creating anonymous subclass. You can: 1) use var to infer the type of the variable. Thus the `lon` variable has more precise type, giving you access to the new method. 2) Use regular subclass if you want to pass this variable somewhere, preserving its type.

Comment: are you referring to something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1958961/16034206)?

Comment: FYI: This is not a "constructor function" (that term doesn't exist in Java), you're creating an anonymous subclass.

Answer (score 5):

You can call it as part of the same statement:

```
new RegularAxis(){
    public String returnHello(){
         return "hello";
    }
}.returnHello();
```

Or you can capture the anonymous type with a `var` variable in Java 10+ (thanks [@Lesiak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73552681/how-to-use-constructor-function-to-add-method-java/73552722#comment129886758_73552681)):

```
var lon = new RegularAxis(){
    public String returnHello(){
         return "hello";
    }
};

lon.returnHello();
```

Otherwise, you'll have to declare it as a proper class:

```
class IrregularAxis extends RegularAxis {
    public String returnHello(){
         return "hello";
    }
}

IrregularAxis lon = new IrregularAxis();
lon.returnHello();
```